# Recorrar tabla con jQuery en una columna especifica

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Buen dia,

Tengo la siguiente tabla que construí dinamicamente con jQuery en una función

```
<table class="clase_tabla_presentaciones_modal_crear_pedido" id="tabla_presentaciones_en_modal_crear_pedido" border="1px">
<thead>
 <tr>
    <th>COD</th>
    <th>NOMBRE</th>
    <th>CANT CAJAS</th>
    <th>PESO CAJA (KG)</th>
    <th>ELIMINAR</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
         <td class="codigo">21</td>
         <td class="nombre">CUADRADA X 1125 G</td>
         <td class="cant_cajas">8</td>
         <td class="peso_caja">9</td>
         <td><button id="21" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Eliminar</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td class="codigo">23</td>
         <td class="nombre">PANELA DULCE X 1125 G</td>
         <td class="cant_cajas">9</td><td class="peso_caja">9</td>
         <td><button id="23" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Eliminar</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td class="codigo">29</td>
         <td class="nombre">REDONDA X1000 GR</td>
         <td class="cant_cajas">25</td>
         <td class="peso_caja">9</td>
         <td><button id="29" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Eliminar</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ahi tengo entonces tres productos, la voy alimentando dinamicamente con otro boton de mas productos, pero no quiero que se repitan, un producto tiene codigo unico asi que lo quiero hacer por codigo,

asi que intento hacer esto

```
$('#tabla_presentaciones_en_modal_crear_pedido tr').each(function(){
     var codigo_iterado = $(this).find(".codigo").html();
   console.log(codigo_iterado);
 });
```

luego de eso quiero hacer un if que compare el codigo_iterado con el codigo que se quiere introducir pero me sale undefined el iterado, ya proble en vez de .html() con .val()

alguna idea?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer elemento te sale undefined porque tu selector es a los tr dentro de elid #tabla_presentaciones_en_modal_crear_pedido y si te fijas tienes un tr en en el thead el cual no tiene dentro la clase .codigo, lo que puedes hacer es el selector a .codigo ya sea directo o pasando por los selectores anteriores:

```
$('#tabla_presentaciones_en_modal_crear_pedido tr .codigo').each(function(){
     var codigo_iterado = $(this).html();
     console.log(codigo_iterado);
 });
```

o

```
$('.codigo').each(function(){
     var codigo_iterado = $(this).html();
     console.log(codigo_iterado);
 });
```